# How to use Jena's Union model with inference rules

Tags: java, jena, semantic-web, turtle-rdf, jena-rules

I'm trying to keep a big model with reference data and in memory and attach other models with inference rules, and I need matching rules to fire when new triples are coming, lookup the reference data and all the new triples to end up in the second model.

Like this:

```
#Reference data:

    :alice
        foaf:name   "Alice" ;
        schema:identifier "1" ;
        .

#New incoming triples:

    :claire
        foaf:name   "Claire" ;
        schema:identifier "3" ;
        :friend_id   "1" ;
        .
```

When Claire arrives a rule should fire, find Alice in reference data by id and generate additional triple like

```
:alice foaf:knows :claire
```

which should end up together with Claire's records in the model being filled, not the same one where Alice resides.

My latest attempt at this:

```
    private void createUnionModel() {
    Model referred = RDFDataMgr.loadModel("referred.ttl");

    Reasoner reasoner = new GenericRuleReasoner(Rule.rulesFromURL("align.sse"));
    Model aligned = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
    Model union = ModelFactory.createUnion(aligned, referred);
    InfModel infModel = ModelFactory.createInfModel(reasoner, union);

    RDFDataMgr.read(infModel, "new_triples.ttl");

    printModel(referred, "referred");
    printModel(aligned, "aligned");
    printModel(union, "union");
    printModel(infModel, "inference");
}
```

shows that triples generated by inference rules don't go into the `aligned` model:

```
'alignment rules loaded' 
'alignment rules loaded' 
 ----------------- referred

:alice  a                  foaf:Person ;
        schema:identifier  "1" ;
        foaf:name          "Alice" .

:bob    a                  foaf:Person ;
        schema:identifier  "2" ;
        foaf:name          "Bob" .


 ----------------- aligned
<http://example.org/claire>
        a                               <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Person> ;
        <http://example.org/friend_id>  "1" ;
        <http://schema.org/identifier>  "3" ;
        <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/name>
                "Claire" .


 ----------------- union

:claire  a                 foaf:Person ;
        :friend_id         "1" ;
        schema:identifier  "3" ;
        foaf:name          "Claire" .

:alice  a                  foaf:Person ;
        schema:identifier  "1" ;
        foaf:name          "Alice" .

:bob    a                  foaf:Person ;
        schema:identifier  "2" ;
        foaf:name          "Bob" .


 ----------------- inference
'alignment rules loaded' 
'rule matched: ' <http://example.org/claire> ' knows ' <http://example.org/alice> 

:claire  a                 foaf:Person ;
        schema:identifier  "3" ;
        foaf:knows         :alice ;
        foaf:name          "Claire" .

:alice  a                  foaf:Person ;
        schema:identifier  "1" ;
        foaf:name          "Alice" .

:bob    a                  foaf:Person ;
        schema:identifier  "2" ;
        foaf:name          "Bob" .
```

I tried to compose the model differently, i.e. first constructing the inference model and then combining it with reference, didn't help.

How can I save triples generated by inference rules in a model separately from lookup data?

Is there a way to define this in `ttl` files instead of Java code?

[Full code of this example on GitHub](https://github.com/utgarda/jena-union-model-example)

Comment: Why just not add these triples to the desired model: `aligned.setNsPrefixes(infModel);
 aligned.add(infModel.getDeductionsModel());` 
The method `org.apache.jena.rdf.model.InfModel#getDeductionsModel()` will return a derivations model, i.e. triple `:alice foaf:knows :claire` in your case

Comment: or create an union from infModel.getDeductionsModel() and aligned, to avoid physical moving data